# Ubuntu 22.04 Wifi adapter (Intel Centrino Ultimate-N 6300) not recognized

Tags: wireless, 22.04, centrino

I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 on Dell Inc. Precision M6700 which is hooked up to a docking station and two external monitors. Prior to upgrading to 22.04, I have been using 21.10 with the same setup without any issues. After upgrading, I have faced multiple issues including every now and then external monitors not being recognized, but the most frustrating has been the issue with wifi. Initially, the wifi connection was spotty (it will connect and upon switching users, it will not recognize the wifi adapter). Now it doesn't ever connect to wifi. I have tried every possible solution I could find online but haven't been able to fix this. The adapter is showing up as unclaimed which I believe indicates that there is no driver for it, but I am not where to go from here. I'll really appreciate any help anyone can provide to help solve this issue.

Output of lshw -c network

```
 *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 04
       serial: f0:1f:af:1f:2b:81
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.15.0-43-generic duplex=full firmware=0.13-3 ip=192.168.1.64 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:33 memory:f7e00000-f7e1ffff memory:f7e39000-f7e39fff ioport:f080(size=32)
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Centrino Ultimate-N 6300
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 35
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f7d00000-f7d01fff
```

Output of lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list:

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) [8086:1502] (rev 04)
    DeviceName:  Onboard LAN
    Subsystem: Dell 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) [1028:053f]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1e2d] (rev 04)
--
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 [8086:422b] (rev 35)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 3x3 AGN [8086:1121]
0c:00.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394) [0c00]: O2 Micro, Inc. 1394 OHCI Compliant Host Controller [1217:13f7] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Dell 1394 OHCI Compliant Host Controller [1028:053f]
1: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
16: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Out of sudo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo dmesg | grep iwl

```
[52515.092241] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
[52515.092246] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:9858:4c7cba27
```

After purging backport, following your (chili555) suggestion, and rebooting, the wifi was connected at the login screen. But after I logged in, it again shows wifi adapter not found.

Output of sudo lshw -class network shows Disabled (was showing unclaimed earlier)

```
 *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 04
       serial: f0:1f:af:1f:2b:81
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.15.0-43-generic duplex=full firmware=0.13-3 ip=192.168.1.64 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:27 memory:f7e00000-f7e1ffff memory:f7e39000-f7e39fff ioport:f080(size=32)
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Ultimate-N 6300
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 35
       serial: 3c:a9:f4:3a:eb:90
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.15.0-43-generic firmware=9.221.4.1 build 25532 6000-4.uc latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:31 memory:f7d00000-f7d01fff
```

Update: I wanted to post this update in case someone else runs into a similar issue. As chilli555 (thank you!) suggested in the comments section, I checked other modules and once I disabled firewire module in bios, I did not experience the issue with wifi. I don't know how those two are connected, but it seems to have solved the problem for me.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo dmesg | grep iwl`  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Please try: `sudo apt purge backport-iwlwifi-dkms` and reboot.

Comment: Is the output of: `rfkill list all` changed? Disabled usually means that the wireless switch or key combination is set to turn off the wireless.

Comment: It did not change. Still showing no for soft and hard blocked. If I turn off the physical switch on the laptop, the wifi setting shows airplane mode, and goes back to wifi adapter not found when turned back on.

Comment: Rebooted again. This time the wifi remained connected after I logged in. I switched between user accounts and it continued to work. At this point, not sure if the problem is permanently fixed. When I initially installed 22.04, the wifi would work but then it would stop working for no obvious reason. I'll monitor it for a day or two and if the problem doesn't come back, I'll mark it as solved. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem is still there. Logged out and in again. Same issue- Wifi adapter not recognized. The wireless interface shows DIASBLED.

Comment: Please run and show: `sudo dmesg | grep -e iwl -e wlp`

Comment: It returns a large amount of text. I have pasted it at https://pastebin.com/VWhLkbQ2
Please let me know if you would like me to edit the original question and include the text there.

Comment: There are numerous repeats of: "Modules linked in: rfcomm ccm cmac algif_hash ..." etc. Something in your system is crashing and restarting. *iwlwifi* is listed as one of the dozens of loaded modules that were loaded, crashed and restarted. I doubt that the crash is started by the wifi. The latest of these that you pasted is at the timestamp [84512.295876]. I suggest that you do: `sudo dmesg | less` and use the arrow keys to scroll down to just before and after the timestamp to see what's going wrong. (Wild guess: since the first module listed is rfcomm, I'd look at bluetooth.)

Comment: It appears that it was firewire that was creating problems. I have disabled firewire in bios and have not experienced the issue with wifi adapter since then. Thanks a lot for your help and pointing me in the right direction.